# ¿Cómo implementar la funcionalidad de preselección de imágenes en Flutter utilizando la librería 'image_picker' o con alguna otra librería?

Tags: flutter, imagen, dart, librería

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación movil en Flutter donde los usuarios pueden seleccionar imágenes. Estoy utilizando la librería image_picker para permitirles seleccionar múltiples imágenes. Sin embargo, me gustaría proporcionar a los usuarios la capacidad de ver y cambiar las imágenes preseleccionadas antes de confirmar su selección final.

Mi objetivo es que cuando un usuario seleccione algunas imágenes y luego vuelva a abrir el selector de imágenes, pueda ver las imágenes que ya ha seleccionado previamente, lo que le permitirá realizar cambios si es necesario antes de guardarlas en la nube.

He explorado la documentación de la librería image_picker y las actualizaciones recientes, pero no he encontrado una forma directa de implementar esta funcionalidad de preselección de imágenes.

¿Alguien podría proporcionar orientación sobre cómo lograr esta funcionalidad utilizando la librería image_picker o si hay alguna alternativa que ofrezca esta característica?

Gracias